# What data structure/algorithm could be used to retrieve a pair of values (before & after) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

What data structure and/or algorithm could be used to retrieve a pair values (immediately before and after with respect to the value being search for). The search value doesn't need to be in the list of elements. I started using a BST, but the leaf nodes are giving some problems. *The implementation is for client-side javascript*

This is the current code:

```
var structs = (function structs() {
    function Node(value) {
        return {
            value: value,
            left: null,
            right: null
        };
    }

    function BSTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    BSTree.prototype = {
        constructor: BSTree,

        add: function (value) {
            var newNode = new Node(value),
                current;

            if (this.root === null) {
                this.root = newNode;
            } else {
                current = this.root;
                while (true) {
                    if (value > current.value) {
                        if (current.right === null) {
                            current.right = newNode;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            current = current.right;
                        }
                    } else if (value < current.value) {
                        if (current.left === null) {
                            current.left = newNode;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            current = current.left;
                        }
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        valuesBeforeAfter: function (value) {
            var current = this.root,
                values = {
                    before: null,
                    after: null
                };

            function getAfter(node) {
                var value = null;
                while (node) {
                    value = node.value;

                    if (node.left) {
                        node = node.left;
                    } else {
                        node = null;
                    }
                }

                return value;
            }

            function getBefore(node) {
                var value = null;
                while (node) {
                    value = node.value;

                    if (node.right) {
                        node = node.right;
                    } else {
                        node = null;
                    }
                }

                return value;
            }

            function isBefore(before) {
                return value - before === 1;
            }

            function isAfter(after) {
                return after - value === 1;
            }

            while (current) {
                if (value < current.value) {
                    if (values.after && isAfter(values.after)) {
                        current = current.left;
                    } else {
                        values.after = current.value;

                        if (current.left && !isBefore(values.before)) {
                            values.before = getBefore(current.left);
                        }

                        current = current.left;
                    }
                } else if (value > current.value) {
                    if (values.before && isBefore(values.before)) {
                        current = current.right;
                    } else {
                        values.before = current.value;

                        if (current.right && !isAfter(values.after)) {
                            values.after = getAfter(current.right);
                        }

                        current = current.right;
                    }
                } else { // problem when the node is also a leaf and not left or right
                    if (current.right && current.left) {
                        values.before = getBefore(current.left);
                        values.after = getAfter(current.right);
                    } else {
                        if (!current.right && !isAfter(values.after)) {
                            values.after = null;
                        }

                        if (!current.left && !isBefore(values.before)) {
                            values.before = null;
                        }

                        if (current.left) {
                            values.before = getBefore(current.left);
                        }

                        if (current.right) {
                            values.after = getAfter(current.right);
                        }
                    }

                    current = null;
                }
            }

            if (values.before > value) {
                values.before = null;
            }

            if (values.after < value) {
                values.after = null;
            }

            return values;
        }
    };

    return {
        BSTree: BSTree
    }
})();
```

Test input:

```
var bst, values;

bst = new BSTree();  
bst.add(4);  
bst.add(1);  
bst.add(3);  
bst.add(5);  
bst.add(9);  
bst.add(6);  
bst.add(2);  
values = bst.valuesBeforeAfter(6); // before = 5; after = null; wrong after should be 9
values = bst.valuesBeforeAfter(7); // before = 6; after = 9;
```

**Note:** The function/method `valuesBeforeAfter` should always return at least one of the values unless the structure is empty. The structure will only hold integer values, and it'll never change after is setup.

Comment: Do you also `add` or `remove` between calls to `valuesBeforeAfter`? Or is it never changed once set up?

Comment: The structure never changes after is setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sorted array can do everything a binary search tree can, except for updates. Since you don't need those, just use a sorted array and a simple binary search :)

```
var values = [4,1,3,5,9,6,2];
values.sort(); 

// assumes that values is sorted and non-empty
function valuesBeforeAfter(x) { 
    var lo = 0, hi = values.length;
    while (lo < hi) {
        var mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;
        if (values[mid] > x) hi = mid;
        else                 lo = mid + 1;
    }
    // lo will be the index of the first element > x 
    // or values.length if no such element exists
    console.log(lo);
    if (lo == values.length) return [values[lo - 1],   null]; 
    else if (lo == 0)        return [null,             values[lo]];
    else                     return [values[lo - 1],   values[lo]];
}
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your solution, if you test the function with 6 it returns [1, null] it should return [5, 9], remember it has to retrieve the immediately before and after values

Comment: @RamónGarcía-Pérez: It returns `[6, 9]`, which I think is correct. You can easily decrement the left index if it is equal

Comment: I see, it works with the array sorted in ascending order, was trying with the array sorted descending order.